# How to GET the logo from a organization in AAD with any Microsoft API?

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am using Microsoft Graph API to GET all photos from groups and users but I don't see any options to read out the brand/organization logo.

How can I get the logo?

Comment: Yes, there is no such ms graph API call that allows to read or write organisation logo as of now. There is already a feature request created in the [Microsoft Graph Feedback Forum](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/19705897-allow-azure-ad-high-level-setting-changes-through). Please upvote it so that it may be implemented in future by product team.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is `beta` version of Microsoft Graph to support [Organization Branding settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/organizationalbrandingproperties?view=graph-rest-beta).

Organization branding settings is there the logo, background, color of the UI customizations are saved.